# Fortran; looping over file names with common attributes

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003, do-loops

I'm fairly new to Fortran and I am having trouble with my file names, I have a bunch of data in simuln#.res (where 1<#<20), I have multiple different directories with all the same simuln#.res names but they had different input parameters. The code looks like this:

```
  character(len=11) :: theFileA
  character(len=12) :: theFileB
  character(len=:), allocatable :: fileplace

  write(*,*) "the directory with the data sets, use quotations"
  read(*,*) fileplace

  fileLoop : do j=1,20
  if (j .lt. 10) then 
    write(theFileA, '("simuln", I1,".res")' ) j   
    open(newunit= iin,file = fileplace//theFileA,status='old')
 else 
    write(theFileB, '("simuln",I2,".res")') j
    open(newunit= iin,file = fileplace//theFileB,status='old')
 end if

does some stuff with the file 
end do fileLoop
```

The code compiles with a gfortran compiler on my mac, but when I put in my path to the directory with the files, it gives the error `simuln1.res does not exist` (which it absolutely does, triple checked). I have tried changing the edit descriptor (and making real(j)), but I still get the same thing. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suggest not using `fortran90` tag, when actually using Fortran 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `fileplace` of deferred length (`(len=:)`), but you appear to not allocate it before attempting the read.

That is, `read(*,*) fileplace` doesn't, under the F2003 rules of automatic allocation, allocate `fileplace` to the correct length and assign.  That means that later on `fileplace` could well be being treated as a zero-length character variable (`''`) in the file to be opened.

To check this hypothesis, try `print *, fileplace//theFileA`.  This could be supported by the fact that the error message refers to just the trailing part of the file's name.

If this is the case, then use a "large" variable.  You say 90 characters is as long as you need, so:

```
character(len=90) :: fileplace    ! Adjust length as desired
...
read(*,*) fileplace
...
open (newunit=iin, file=TRIM(fileplace)//theFileA, status='old')
...
```

Ensure you append the file's name to the trimmed directory name to avoid having spaces between the two parts.

[As a side note, you appear to not need `theFileA` and `theFileB`; just use the latter, considering that trailing blanks are ignored.  And you may well want to force a trailing '/' on `fileplace`.]

Comment: thanks! So I made my fileplace a length of 90, because that is the string of my longest path name but then it comes with this error because there is blank space between the fileplace and theFileA. If I remember correctly you can use this trim(adjust1(fileplace//theFileA)). But I don't seem to have adjust1 as a function `Error: Function 'adjust1' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`. Do you have another suggestion on something I could use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using `1` instead of `L` in `adjustl` ?

Comment: :/ yes, ok fixed that although its did not seem to trim the excess off , now I get `/Users/mesmith/Documents/repos/lee-simplified/src/simulnOutput/gas/noCoulomb/             simuln1.res` as the print of `print *, fileplace//theFileA`

Comment: Also, meant to add this in the last comment I also added in a buffer variable (with length of 90) and then I assign `filepath = trim(adjustl(buffer))`, I though that it should automatically allocate filepath to the correct trimmed length?

Comment: @user3346946 In this simple case you perhaps don't benefit from having the automatic allocation, having two versions of the path.  Do ensure you use `trim` (with `adjustl` if you like also) before the `//`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for all the help. It turns out the gfortran compiler I was using was an older version (4.6.2), I then looked up to make sure that this version of the compiler had allocatable strings and found that it has a reported but about it crashing. So I pushed my changes to git so I could access it from my work computer and then my code worked! I will have to update my personal computer with the newest gfortran compiler. Thanks for all the help!!