# Fortran90 : read file names sequentially

Tags: loops, directory, fortran

I am working with `fortran 90`. I have 50 `.dat` files that correspond to 50 time steps. Files have a similar name, for instance `tstep01.dat`, `tstep02.dat`, `tstep03.dat`, etc. I have to read sequentially the name of these files. Files are loacted in the `output` directory that is in the same directory as my script. I want to get the name of files in order to pass it to a subroutine that generates animation. The subroutine gets this name to read the data and creates .png frames subsequently. I have already tried this:

```
  character(len = 14) :: data_name    !data  name
  nframes = 50  !number of timesteps
  do i = 1, nframes
    write(data_name,  '(output/("/tstep", I2.2, ".dat"))') i 
  end do
```

but I got this error :

```
write(data_name,  ('output/("/tstep", I2.2, ".dat")')) i   
                 1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
```

I think the problem is with the `output/`, but I don't know what is the correct way for defining the directory of files. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your intention with the `read` statement, you probably want to use a `write` statement here to create a filename (note the length of the character variable should a bit larger as well). With this filename you will probably want to open the file and read the file.

Comment: In fact, I want to get the name of files in order to pass it to a subroutine that generates animation. The subroutine gets this name to read the data and creates .png frames subsequently.

Comment: @albert I corrected my code according to your comment. I changed `read` with `write`. I still have problems with the directory definition, I think.

Comment: well length is still to small, and the format statement is not correct either, probably should be something like `'("output/tstep", I2.2, ".dat")'`

Comment: Thanks @albert! the problem is solved!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fortran; looping over file names with common attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000443/fortran-looping-over-file-names-with-common-attributes)

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thanks for your remark! but I had seen the question that you mentioned before having had asked my question. I did not find a solution to my problem in that question.